# Building thrift c glib

Tags: c, thrift, glib

I used the thrift compiler to generate C-glib files. However they never seem to compile.

My .c file:

```
#include "zipkin_core_types.h"

void genLogfile(Span span, char *filename) {
}
```

My .h file

```
#include "zipkin_core_types.h"

#ifndef SPANLOGGERCH
#define SPANLOGGERCH

void genLogfile(Span span, char *filename);

#endif
```

command line options:

```
gcc -g -o  main -I/usr/include/glib-2.0/ -I /usr/lib/glib/include/ -I/usr/local/include/thrift/ -I/usr/local/include/thrift/c_glib -I. -L/usr/local/lib/-I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include/  -lthrift  main.c zipkin_core_types.c SpanLoggerC.c
```

I get 5 screens of error messages. Here's the top few lines, they mostly look like this. Any suggestions woule be appreciated:

```
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gboxed.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:25,
                 from zipkin_core_types.h:11,
                 from SpanLoggerC.h:1,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:41: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘typedef’
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:90: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gboxed.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:25,
                 from zipkin_core_types.h:11,
                 from SpanLoggerC.h:1,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/garray.h:32: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘G_BEGIN_DECLS’
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/garray.h:40: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘gchar’
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/garray.h:66: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/garray.h:69: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/garray.h:73: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

Comment: I tried similar things and it works well. So would you please try something like
    #include <glib-object.h> 
and compile it with
    gcc -c test.c -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib/include

Comment: Thanks Henry! The glib-2.0 seems to the missing include,

Comment: You should have mentioned CentOS in your question. There are some special steps required for CentOS, which are [outlined on the Thrift web site](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/centos). If that solves the issue, please close the [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2447).